# PHP Runkit Sandbox in iFrame

Tags: javascript, php, runkit

Would it be possible for me to make an iFrame run PHP using Runkit_Sandbox so that its safe and doesn't effect the server. For example if I update the contents of the iFrame with php code, it will be run through Runkit Sandbox making it not part of the server essentially.

Is this possible and what would the code be like?

Comment: Its been quite a while. Usually I wait a couple hours to see if someone will respond but nobody is :(

Comment: What you're describing doesn't make a lot of sense. An iframe is a client-side entity; it can't run PHP code.

Comment: Exactly but I was wondering if theres some way to do a sort of console output I guess you could call it. @duskwuff